# HTML dropdown boxes to form URL

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have an archive of pages on my website which are in dated folders and are accessed by going to www.mysite.com/archive/yyyy_mm_dd

I want to use dropdown boxes - one for year, one for month and one for day - which can form a URL on my site to go to.

For example, if my dropdown boxes show "2013" for year, "10" for month and "15" for day, the URL produced would be www.mysite.com/archive/2013_10_15

I've looked online and have found how to incorporate the output of a single dropdown box into a URL but how could I form a URL from multiple dropdowns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

UPDATED: with implementation example: http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/sETsW/7/

```
<select class='day'>
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
</select>    

<select class='month'>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>05</option>
</select> 

<select class='year'>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
</select> 

<form action="" id="dateForm" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>    


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    day = currentDate.getDate(),
    month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
    year = currentDate.getFullYear();

url = year+'_'+month+'_'+day;

$('select').change(function()
    {
        var day = $('.day').val(),
            month = $('.month').val(),
            year  = $('.year').val();  

         url = 'http://mysite.com/archive/'+year+'_'+month+'_'+day;
         $('#dateForm').attr('action', url);

         console.log(url);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Should probably add a conditional that tests that all drop-downs have a value before processing.

Comment: @spacebean, doesnt this cahnge page even if only one of data,month or year is cahnged. Doenst the user need to specify all of them. I think a simple form would be better.

Comment: This is true. I am assuming they all have default values (e.g. yesterdays date) in this case. If that is not true, then it would need the condition.

Comment: It doesn't change any page, it just sets the url variable. I am assuming the user has to take some action such as hitting a submit button before the url variable is used.

Comment: Thank you very much spacebean - this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: Just one more thing - it works fine in the implementation example but nothing happens when I click 'Submit' if I test it locally or on my server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but make sure you are including the jquery library and the custom code is included after it. If that's not the issue, maybe you can post a link to your implementation?

Comment: What would I have to do to include the jquery library? I think that's what I'm doing wrong. Sorry for my lack of knowledge on this!

Comment: No problem, I edited the example. Just add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` above the other script.

Answer (score 0):

Why use drop down when there is nice datepicker option for you provided by jquery..You can just set any of the format needed..with dropdown the user has to select three dropdown which is not so ease..and with jquery datepicker plugin you can have just a single values box with limited dates as you want.

You can have a look at the [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) plugin, if you are interested in this implementation.

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VnbxH/)